# Ver estructurado un CSS que está a una sola linea

Tags: css, notepad++

En diversas ocasiones me veo en la necesidad de modificar archivos CSS que están escritos en una misma línea.

Uso el Notepad++ para estas modificaciones pero el problema es que incluso con el ajuste de línea, es muy complicado leerlo, localizar el alcance de una regla y por supuesto realizar las modificaciones oportunas.

Quisiera saber si con el propio Notepad++ o con cualquier otro soft se puede ver el CSS estructurado en su cascada original.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Normalmente, las preguntas que piden recomendaciones de software no se aceptan al haber la posibilidad de que estén basadas en opiniones. Dicho esto, yo te recomendaría usar alguna herramienta online tipo [css beautify](https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/)

Answer (score 1):

Antes de copiarlo al notepadd pulsa el boton "{}" del inspector (abajo del codigo css a la izquierda) cuando veas el código minificado y lo formateara, es la forma mas rapida y sin urls...

Ademas, tanto notepad++ como la mayoria de editores serios permiten instalar plugins para hacerlo

Comment: Si con el inspector se puede hacer, para echar un vistazo me vendrá genial, pero creo que lo que buscaré como mejor solución es un plugin para notepad++ que haga esto, así me será más cómodo.

Muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Los archivos tanto js y css que encuentres escritos en una sola línea, es porque estan minificados, lo que debes hacer para poder editarlos, es usar alguna herramienta en línea que te permita desminificar el archivo, por ejemplo podrías usar esta:
https://unminify.com/

Ahí copias tu línea de código y te devolverá desminificado, luego para volverla a guardar en tu proyecto, puedes usar otra herramienta en línea para minificar el códgio como esta:
https://www.minifier.org/

Minify es una técnica que se usa para hacer más liviana nuestra página web, te recomiendo leer un poco más acerca de esto.
http://www.4rsoluciones.com/blog/minificar-codigo-una-tecnica-sencilla-para-hacer-mas-liviano-nuestro-sitio-web/

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte. He probado algunas páginas pero no lo había conseguido, probaré la que me indicas.